# Reemplazar Iframe dentro de div Creado por Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Que tal tengo problemas con el mi codigo
estoy creando un iframe que consulta un servicio, asi que creo la url con parámetros hacia la creación del iframe, luego lo envio hacia un div en html, todo esto con una funcion que se activa con un boton, el problema es que al presionar el boton de nuevo no reemplaza el div si no que dibuja otro adjunto codigo

```
var x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
            x.style.width = "1280px";
            x.style.height = "480px";
            x.setAttribute("src", link);
            document.getElementById("iframe").appendChild(x);
```

creo el div

```
div id="iframe"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tu problema es por que nunca limpias el div, y le pones un appendChild, esto lo que hará es añadir el elemento nuevo a los child de tu elemento.

```
document.getElementById("iframe").innerHTML = ''; //Lo borras y luego metes nuevo valor.
```

```js
function addiframe(url) {
  var x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
  x.style.width = "300px";
  x.style.height = "300px";
  x.setAttribute("src", url);
  document.getElementById("iframe").innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById("iframe").appendChild(x);
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  addiframe('https://codepen.io/');
});
```

```html
<button onclick="addiframe('https://es.stackoverflow.com/')">Reemplazar</button>
<div id="iframe"></div>
```